# Scatter angles at IceCube

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrinos

Is it possible to have a scatter angle(in lab frame) to be greater than 90 degrees at IceCube, with this I mean the relative angle between the incoming (muon) neutrino and the outgoing (muon)lepton.

$$\nu_\mu + N \rightarrow \mu^- + X$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly *possible*, though the odds that such a neutrino interaction would actually be observed are negligible.

The incoming neutrino--outgoing lepton angle is a function of both particles' energies.  In the center-of-momentum frame, the angle is unconstrained; but if the initial neutrino has a large initial energy, boosting back to the lab frame boosts the outgoing lepton in a preferentially forward direction.  On the other hand, in the COM frame the outgoing lepton and other outgoing particle(s) divide up the total momentum transfer evenly, and because their 3-momenta sum to zero, an outgoing lepton with small momenta can wind up at a very large angle relative to the incoming neutrino direction so long as its momentum along the incoming neutrino direction is balanced by the other particles.

Here's an illustration from neutrino interactions that I cooked up using the output one of the standard neutrino interaction simulations used in neutrino experiments, [GENIE](https://www.genie-mc.org/), that I had lying around.  The simulation here is for interactions on carbon, not oxygen (which will dominate at IceCube, given that it's all water), but the answer won't be much different.

[image: probability of neutrino interactions with a given outgoing lepton angle vs incident neutrino energy]

Here each column sums to unit probability, so that you can see the probabilities of lepton angle (y-axis) for a given neutrino energy (x-axis).  You can see hopefully that at lower energies, opening angles of >90 deg (= cos(angle) < 0) are possible but unlikely.  The probability decreases rapidly as you go up in energy.

The neutrino interactions that IceCube actually reconstructs predominantly come from neutrinos in the 100s of GeV and above (though the so-called "DeepCore" upgrade has reduced this to the ~10 GeV region).  (See the [IceCube](https://icecube.wisc.edu/science/research/) website for more on this.)  So it will be exceptionally rare for them to reconstruct one of these "backwards" leptons (and probably even more rare to get its direction right; my guess is their reconstruction assumes the lepton always goes more or less in the neutrino direction).